# Try to catch nodes info from with useStaticQuery of Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to catch info from GraphQL Gatsby with `useStaticQuery` but the data returned is `undefined` and I don't understand why because in my `http://localhost:8000/___graphql` I received the good information.

My code is not a page component it's a reason why I used `Static Query`

My code is like that:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useStaticQuery, graphql} from "gatsby";


export default function MenuMD () {
    const { data } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
                allFile(filter: {sourceInstanceName: {eq: "markdown"}}) {
                    edges {
                        node {
                            childrenMarkdownRemark {
                                frontmatter {
                                    slug
                                    title
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
      }
    `
    )
    console.log('static data', data);

    return<>Menu from MarkDown</>
}
```

the expected result from `http://localhost:8000/___graphql` is something like that:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allFile": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "childMarkdownRemark": {
              "frontmatter": {
                "slug": "/projet_m",
                "title": "Projet M"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "childMarkdownRemark": {
              "frontmatter": {
                "slug": "/projet_n",
                "title": "Projet N"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "extensions": {}
}
```

May be there is a reason for this `undefined` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the query is working in the GraphiQL environment and there's a `"markdown"` `sourceInstanceName` in your data structure, try it like this:

```
export default function MenuMD() {
  const data = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        allFile(filter: { sourceInstanceName: { eq: "markdown" } }) {
          edges {
            node {
              childrenMarkdownRemark {
                frontmatter {
                  slug
                  title
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  );
  console.log("static data", data);

  return <>Menu from MarkDown</>;
}
```

There's nothing wrong using a static query in a component rather than a page, the result must be exactly the same (in terms of output).

Your data should be inside `data.allFile.edges` (or d'estructures directly as `{ allFile }`) not directly destructuring the result of the static query as `data`. That's why `data` was `undefined` in your case.

Comment: You'r amazing... just remove the ugly {} and that's work like a charm :)